# Do I need to stay continuously logged in to Find my Mac to see if a stolen laptop becomes active?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipod-touch, find-my-mac

My Macbook Pro was stolen 3 months ago and I am giving up hope of finding it. I was very much hoping to locate it- not so much for the extensive valuable information I have on it, but because the laptop was taken in the context of an assault on a young child. Recovery of it has been deemed necessary for prosecution. I have Find my Iphone activated on my Ipod 4 (so IOS 6.1.3) and check it each day, but the Macbook is always listed as "offline". My log-in time doesn't last long- I'm "kicked off" after a short time. I also clicked an option for a sound to indicate whether the laptop had been activated.

One question is whether it would tell me if it had been activated in the intervening time, between log-ins? Sometimes my replacement laptop says it is offline- but I used it within 24 hours. Are we expected to log in continuously around the clock to track a device?

Comment: Can you please post "Another question is whether there is any way to get the serial number from Apple. I know when I activated the laptop initially I had to register (or what I thought was registration). Unfortunately I thought the serial number was on the store receipt I kept, but it was not. I did not purchase a repair plan." -- as a separate question? Questions on Ask Different should be as close to singular as possible. Thanks.